# Creating a clear cells button that contains a confirmation dialogue prior to running the script

Tags: google-apps-script

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eh0tFgd8_hbE-z0hkfVpFoWCLVSyjQx8gOwZj-gUyAs/edit#gid=1839188589

in the sheet linked above there is a button to clear certain cells. 
what I need to know is if it can be setup so that when we click the clear button it asks for a confirmation of the delete before it clears the cells?

Answer (score 1):

Sure. You could use `SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt()` there are several flavors take a look at them [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui.html).  They also have examples to view. [Here's an example I did yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58677461/7215091)